# Queue not filling

Tags: python-3.x, queue

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Queue system in python.
In the code below I'm trying to use two threads, one that begins an update function feeds data into a put() and one that takes data from the put() with get() and updates the chart with that data.

However, using print statements show that it is putting "None" into put() and the get() seems to get some data somehow but only  twice, and only the same data.
However, the rest of the thread() function is certainly adding more and more data to the data list

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot, QtCore, QtGui
import sys 
import os
from random import randint
import time
import threading
import os
import queue
import random
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.flagHasData = False

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data 
        self.flagHasData = True
        self.generatePicture()
        self.informViewBoundsChanged()
        


    def generatePicture(self):
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        w = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close, min, max) in self.data:
            p.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(t, min), QtCore.QPointF(t, max))
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(t-w, open, w*2, close-open))
        p.end()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        if self.flagHasData:
            p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

data = [  
    [1., 10, 13, 5, 15],
    [2., 13, 17, 9, 20],
    [3., 17, 14, 11, 23],
    [4., 14, 15, 5, 19],
    [5., 15, 9, 8, 22],
    [6., 9, 15, 8, 16],
]
item = CandlestickItem()
item.set_data(data)

plt = pg.plot()
plt.addItem(item)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customGraphicsItem')
q = queue.Queue()

def update():
    global item, data
    while True:
        data_len = len(data)
        rand = random.randint(0, len(data)-1)
        new_bar = data[rand][:]
        new_bar[0] = data_len
        data.append(new_bar)
        q.put(data)
        print("putting data " + str(q.put(data)))
        
        # print(data)
        time.sleep(1)

    # app.processEvents() 

def startTheThread():

    t = threading.Thread(target = update, args = ())
    t.start()
    
def startTheThread_2():
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = thread, args = ())
    t2.start()
    
    
def thread():
    while not q.empty():
        i = q.get()
        print("getting data " + str(i))
        print(i)
        item.set_data(i)
        # CandlestickItem(i) 
        q.task_done() 
        
        
startTheThread()
startTheThread_2()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

This is the output of this code until I stop it's execution.

```
putting data Nonegetting data [[1.0, 10, 13, 5, 15], [2.0, 13, 17, 9, 

20], [3.0, 17, 14, 11, 23], [4.0, 14, 15, 5, 19], [5.0, 15, 9, 8, 22], [6.0, 9, 15, 8, 16], [6, 17, 14, 11, 23]]
[[1.0, 10, 13, 5, 15], [2.0, 13, 17, 9, 20], [3.0, 17, 14, 11, 23], [4.0, 14, 15, 5, 19], [5.0, 15, 9, 8, 22], [6.0, 9, 15, 8, 16], [6, 17, 14, 11, 23]]
getting data [[1.0, 10, 13, 5, 15], [2.0, 13, 17, 9, 20], [3.0, 17, 14, 11, 23], [4.0, 14, 15, 5, 19], [5.0, 15, 9, 8, 22], [6.0, 9, 15, 8, 16], [6, 17, 14, 11, 23]]
[[1.0, 10, 13, 5, 15], [2.0, 13, 17, 9, 20], [3.0, 17, 14, 11, 23], [4.0, 14, 15, 5, 19], [5.0, 15, 9, 8, 22], [6.0, 9, 15, 8, 16], [6, 17, 14, 11, 23]]

putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
putting data None
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that your `thread` function ends when the queue has run out of items. You probably want to it run indefinitely (perhaps until a specific sentinel value is sent through the queue to tell it to quit).

Comment: q.task_done() only ends the current queue item though right? Also the while statement in that function will ensure it continuously re-attempts the q.get().
Also that doesn't explain why the q.put() is returning None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of issues in your code. But the main issue is very simple, your `thread` function that gets data from the queue exits as soon as the queue is empty. It loops with `while not q.empty():`, which will only last until it's consumed all the currently available data. Then it quits and never checks again.

Likely you want to to loop indefinitely. Just a simple `while True` will do that for you, as `q.get` will block for as long as necessary, if there's no data currently available.

Among the other issues in your code:

- Every time you do `q.put(data)`, you're putting a reference to the same list of lists, `data`. This is problematic if you want the unchanged data to be processed first, before the updated data gets processed in a later step. If the queue is actually holding several updates at once, you'd then see the most recent version of the data processed several times. Copying `data` before putting it into the queue should fix this.
- The `print` call you have in `update` causes you to `put` to the queue twice. And since `put` doesn't return anything, you always get `None` in your output. Probably you want to be printing `data` instead of the return value from `put` (and certainly not calling it twice).

Comment: Thank you so much for your input!
This has resolved my issue, however what specifically do you mean by "Copying data"? in your second suggestion?

Comment: Something like `q.put(copy.deepcopy(data))`